# Trouble with acceptance specs hanging with Rails 3.1.4, capybara-webkit 0.11.0, unicorn 4.3.1 and shared DB hack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capybara, unicorn, capybara-webkit

We've recently tried upgrading an app from Rails 3.0.12 to 3.1.4, and now a number of acceptance specs using capybara-webkit for JS testing are hanging or displaying transient failures with assorted database errors.

We have a fairly common hack in our spec_helper.rb that shares a DB connection between the spec itself and the server that capybara-webkit spawns. I suspect that we may be having some kind of deadlock and/or race condition between these threads.

Googling around suggests that Unicorn doesn't work well with this hack (though it used to just fine), so I tried switching to thin and WEBrick in turn: both of those just locked up.

Gemfile.lock is as follows:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.12)
      actionpack (= 3.0.12)
      mail (~> 2.2.19)
    actionpack (3.0.12)
      activemodel (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
      rack (~> 1.2.5)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.14)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
    activerecord (3.0.12)
      activemodel (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      arel (~> 2.0.10)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.12)
      activemodel (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
    activesupport (3.0.12)
    addressable (2.2.8)
    airbrake (3.0.9)
      activesupport
      builder
    archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
    arel (2.0.10)
    aws-s3 (0.6.2)
      builder
      mime-types
      xml-simple
    aws-sdk (1.4.1)
      httparty (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bourne (1.1.2)
      mocha (= 0.10.5)
    bson (1.6.2)
    bson_ext (1.6.2)
      bson (~> 1.6.2)
    builder (2.1.2)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    capybara-webkit (0.11.0)
      capybara (>= 1.0.0, < 1.2)
      json
    childprocess (0.3.2)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    chronic (0.6.7)
    clearance (0.16.1)
      diesel (~> 0.1.5)
      rails (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coderay (1.0.6)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    cucumber (1.2.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.10.0)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.8)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    database_cleaner (0.7.2)
    debugger (1.1.3)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.1.1)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.1.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.1.1)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (>= 1.1.1)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.2)
    delayed_job (3.0.2)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
      activerecord (> 2.1.0)
      delayed_job (~> 3.0.0)
    diesel (0.1.5)
      railties
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    dynamic_form (1.1.4)
    email_spec (1.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.2)
      rspec (~> 2.0)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    escape (0.0.4)
    excon (0.13.4)
    factory_girl (3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (3.2.0)
      factory_girl (~> 3.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    fakeweb (1.3.0)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    flay (1.4.3)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    flog (2.5.3)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    flutie (1.3.3)
    formtastic (1.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 2.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.7)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
    gherkin (2.10.0)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    haml (3.1.5)
    haml-rails (0.3.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      haml (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
    heroku (2.25.0)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      netrc (~> 0.7.1)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
    heroku-api (0.1.3)
      excon (~> 0.13.3)
    heroku_san (2.2.2)
      heroku (>= 2)
      heroku-api (>= 0.1.2)
      rake
    high_voltage (1.1.1)
    httparty (0.8.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml
    i18n (0.5.0)
    json (1.7.1)
    jwt (0.1.4)
      json (>= 1.2.4)
    kgio (2.7.4)
    launchy (2.1.0)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    libwebsocket (0.1.3)
      addressable
    linecache (0.46)
      rbx-require-relative (> 0.0.4)
    linecache19 (0.5.12)
      ruby_core_source (>= 0.1.4)
    mail (2.2.19)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    metaclass (0.0.1)
    method_source (0.7.1)
    mime-types (1.18)
    mixpanel (1.1.3)
      escape
      json
      rack
    mixpanel_client (2.2.1)
      json (~> 1.6)
    mocha (0.10.5)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    mongo (1.6.2)
      bson (~> 1.6.2)
    mongoid (2.2.6)
      activemodel (~> 3.0.0)
      mongo (~> 1.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
    multi_json (1.3.4)
    multi_xml (0.5.0)
    netrc (0.7.1)
    newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.2)
    paperclip (3.0.3)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    parallel (0.5.16)
    parallel_tests (0.8.1)
      parallel
    pg (0.13.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.9.4)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.7.1)
      slop (>= 2.4.4, < 3)
    pry-doc (0.4.1)
      pry (>= 0.9.0)
      yard (~> 0.7.4)
    pry_debug (0.0.1)
      pry (~> 0.9.0)
    rack (1.2.5)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.12)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.12)
      actionpack (= 3.0.12)
      activerecord (= 3.0.12)
      activeresource (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.12)
    railties (3.0.12)
      actionpack (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    raindrops (0.8.0)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    reek (1.2.8)
      ruby2ruby (~> 1.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.10.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.10.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.10.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.10.0)
    rspec-core (2.10.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.10.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.10.1)
    rspec-rails (2.10.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.10.0)
    ruby-debug (0.10.4)
      columnize (>= 0.1)
      ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.4.0)
    ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
      linecache (>= 0.3)
    ruby2ruby (1.3.1)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
      archive-tar-minitar (>= 0.5.2)
    ruby_parser (2.3.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.8)
    sass (3.1.17)
    selenium-webdriver (2.21.2)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
      libwebsocket (~> 0.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
    sexp_processor (3.2.0)
    sham_rack (1.3.4)
      rack
    shoulda (2.11.3)
    shoulda-matchers (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    show_me_the_cookies (1.1.0)
      capybara (~> 1.0)
    sinatra (1.2.8)
      rack (~> 1.1)
      tilt (>= 1.2.2, < 2.0)
    slop (2.4.4)
    steak (2.0.0)
      capybara (>= 1.0.0)
      rspec-rails (>= 2.5.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    timecop (0.3.5)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twilio-rb (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      httparty (>= 0.6.1)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
      jwt (>= 0.1.3)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    unicorn (4.3.1)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    uuidtools (2.1.2)
    validation_reflection (1.0.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)
    xml-simple (1.1.1)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yard (0.7.5)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  airbrake
  aws-s3
  aws-sdk
  bourne
  bson_ext
  capybara
  capybara-webkit
  chronic
  clearance
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  debugger
  delayed_job
  delayed_job_active_record
  dynamic_form
  email_spec (~> 1.1)
  factory_girl_rails
  fakeweb
  flay
  flog
  flutie
  formtastic (= 1.2.2)
  haml-rails
  heroku_san
  high_voltage
  linecache
  linecache19
  mixpanel
  mixpanel_client
  mongoid
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri
  paperclip
  parallel_tests
  pg
  pry
  pry-doc
  pry_debug
  rack
  rails (~> 3.0.12)
  reek
  rspec-rails
  ruby-debug
  sass
  sham_rack
  shoulda
  shoulda-matchers
  show_me_the_cookies
  sinatra
  steak
  timecop
  twilio-rb
  unicorn
  validation_reflection
  will_paginate
```

And spec_helper.rb is as follows:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'clearance/testing'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :mocha

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.before(:each) do
    Mixpanel::Tracker.stubs(:new).with(MIXPANEL_TOKEN, Mocha::ParameterMatchers::KindOf.new(Hash)).returns(FakeMixpanelTracker)
    FakeMixpanelTracker.clear_tracked_events
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    User::SegmentationData.delete_all
    User::SegmentationResults.delete_all
  end
end

# Big Fat Hack (TM) so the ActiveRecord connections are shared across threads.
# This is a variation of a hack you can find all over the web to make
# capybara usable without having to switch to non transactional
# fixtures.
# http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/248e89ae2acbf603/e5da9e9bfac733e0
Thread.main[:activerecord_connection] = ActiveRecord::Base.retrieve_connection

def (ActiveRecord::Base).connection
  Thread.main[:activerecord_connection]
end

require 'capybara-webkit'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

# Hack to allow us to use regular controller tests to test SmsController 
# (which is an ActionController::Metal).

def metal_testing_hack(klass)
  klass.class_eval do
    include ActionController::UrlFor
    include ActionController::Testing
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    include ActionController::Compatibility    
  end
end

require 'ruby-debug'
Rails.logger.level = 4
```

Any advice would be most appreciated.